# Type 'Element' is missing the following properties from type 'OfferProps': id, firstName, city, price, and 2 more. TS2740

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types, react-props

I'm trying to use render an array of elements, and I'm getting this error in my component

> Type 'Element' is missing the following properties from type 'OfferProps': id, firstName, city, price, and 2 more.  TS2740

My code:

`OffersComponent`

```
import React from 'react';
import { OffersProps } from './types';
import { OfferComponent } from '../OfferComponent/OfferComponent';
import { OfferProps } from '../OfferComponent/types';

export const OffersComponent = ({ dataset }: OffersProps) /* I tried adding :Element[] here, but no luck*/ => dataset.map(
  ({
    id, firstName, city, price, image, description,
  }): OfferProps => (
    // Here's the error
    <OfferComponent id={id} firstName={firstName} city={city} price={price} image={image} description={description} />
  ),
);
```

`OffersProps`

```
import { OfferProps } from '../OfferComponent/types';

export interface OffersProps {
  dataset: OfferProps[];
}
```

`OfferComponent`

```
import React from 'react';
import { OfferProps } from './types';

export const OfferComponent = ({ id, firstName, city, price, image, description }: OfferProps) => (
  <div>
    <div>{`${id}`}</div>
    <div>{firstName}</div>
    <div>{city}</div>
    <div>{`${price} pln`}</div>
    <img src={image} alt={description} />
    <div>{description}</div>
    ===============================
  </div>
);
```

`OfferProps`

```
export interface OfferProps {
  id: {};
  firstName: string;
  city: string;
  price: number;
  image: string;
  description: string;
}
```

As far as I understand it's because I'm returning an array of elements, but why then doesn't adding `:Element[]` fix things? Or am I completely wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something is wrong with your component return type

Try:

```
export const OffersComponent = ({ dataset }: OffersProps) => dataset.map(
  ({
    id, firstName, city, price, image, description,
  }) => (
    // Here's the error
    <OfferComponent id={id} firstName={firstName} city={city} price={price} image={image} description={description} />
  ),
);
```

Comment: Yup this works. The only thing is now I'm getting a `Type 'Element[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Element': type, props, key  TS2605` Any idea what that's about?

Comment: Can you post the new `OffersComponent` function signature?

Comment: I fixed it by adding `: Function` after `OffersComponent`. I found it in another answer. Not sure why, but it works